# multiple relation between two entity doesn't work?

Tags: symfony

I have multiple relation between two entity "user" and "file manager"

a user can have many files

a user can have only one avatar

i handle this relation like this:

```
class Users extends BaseUser
{
/**
     * @var File
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\File",cascade={"persist"})
     * @Assert\Valid()
     */
    private $avatar;


    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\File",mappedBy="user",cascade={"persist"})
     */
    private $files;

 public function __construct()
    {
        $this->sessions = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->departments = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->jobTitles = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->sessionMessages = new ArrayCollection();
        $this->files = new ArrayCollection();
        parent::__construct();
    }


 /**
     * @return File
     */
    public function getAvatar()
    {
        return $this->avatar;
    }
 /**
     * @param File $avatar
     */
    public function setAvatar(File $avatar=null)
    {
        $this->avatar = $avatar->getId();
        $avatar->setUser($this);
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection|File[]
     */
    public function getFiles()
    {
        return $this->files;
    }

    public function addFile(File $file)
    {
        if (!$this->files->contains($file) && !is_null($file)) {
            $this->files[] = $file;
            $file->setUser($this);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    public function removeFile(File $file)
    {
        if ($this->files->contains($file)) {
            $this->files->removeElement($file);
            // set the owning side to null (unless already changed)
            if ($file->getUser() === $this) {
                $file->setUser(null);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }


}
```

and this is my file entity

```
class File
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="boolean",nullable=true)
     *
     */
    private $status;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $path;

    /**
     * @var Users
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Users",inversedBy="files")
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     *@Assert\File()
     */
    private $file;

    /**
     * Sets file.
     *
     * @param UploadedFile $file
     */
    public function setFile(UploadedFile $file = null)
    {
        $this->file = $file;
    }

    /**
     * Get file.
     *
     * @return UploadedFile
     */
    public function getFile()
    {
        return $this->file;
    }

    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getStatus(): ?bool
    {
        return $this->status;
    }

    public function setStatus(bool $status): self
    {
        $this->status = $status;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getName(): ?string
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName(string $name): self
    {
        $this->name = $name;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getPath(): ?string
    {
        return $this->path;
    }

    public function setPath(string $path): self
    {
        $this->path = $path;

        return $this;
    }

    public function getUser(): ?Users
    {
        return $this->user;
    }

    public function setUser($user)
    {if (!is_null($this->file)){
        $this->user = $user;
    }


        return $this;
    }
}
```

the problem is when i submit my registration form i  have an error that says file couldnot be upload firsi i guess it is because my formType that is like that:

```
class RegistrationType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
 ->add('avatar', FileManagerType::class,[
                'data_class'=>File::class,
                'by_reference'=>false
            ])
            ->add('files', CollectionType::class,[
                "entry_type"=> UserFileManagerType::class,
                "allow_add" => true,
                "allow_delete"=>true
            ])

. . .
```

but it is not, the problem is the id of the fileType for the avatar is null after submit and so couldn't be uploaded.

Answer (score 2):

after checking my code and symfony documentation finally i realize it could be fixed by changing my user class like this:

```
public function setAvatar(File $avatar=null)
    {
        $this->avatar = $avatar->getId();
        $avatar->setUser($this);
    }
```

as you see it is so easy but take my time a lot, i hope it helps other

### UPDATE

I found another problem in my code that causes file error,
my fileName for some reason was invalid so **move** function return false so I replace it with following and it works correctly

```
$fileName = $files->getFilename().'.'.$files->guessExtension();
 $result= $files->move($this->resumePath,$fileName);
```